# How to get model after binding but before validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-filters

Is it possible to make a global interception for a model just after it is created in binder but before it is validating. I tried filters, but filter is invoked after validation.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class CustomModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        //You now have access to "bindingContext.Model" which is your model.
    }
}
```

And then in `Application_Start` in `Globals.asax` (don't forget this part):

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a custom model binder. That will intercept the request pipeline before model validation. Implement `IModelBinder`.

Comment: This works only for a particular model, not for all.